# Adding a filter to find out remote IP address of requester using JdkHttpServerFactory

Tags: rest, jersey, glassfish

Is there any way to get the remote IP address while sticking to the JdkHttpServerFactory framework?

I have a very light RESTful server which uses JdkHttpServerFactory to create a server, essentially with one line of code:

JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config);

My dependencies are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

It appears it is not trivial to add a filter to this framework.  I have tried it by bringing in HttpServletRequest but this means I need to bring in the servlet framework, and this actually didn't work for me with JdkHttpServerFactory,  I end up getting null as my request.

I found another suggestion, but that suggestion also meant switching over to using Grizly2,  which agains means I have to abandon the simple/light JdkHttpServerFactory method.

Comment: The only way I can see to access to the IP is through the [`HttpExchange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html). This is not exposed to us. Maybe you can make a feature request to expose the IP and [add it as a property in the ContainerRequest](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jdk-http/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jdkhttp/JdkHttpHandlerContainer.java#L152) or if you really wanted it you can rewrite the module to add it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see to access the IP is through the [`HttpExchange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html). Unfortunately, this is not something that is exposed to us. You can either make a feature request to expose the IP or you can just modify it yourself and build your own artifact. In either case, the change I would suggest making is to just add a property in to the `ContainerRequest`, that you could pull out in your filter.

If you look here in the [source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.27/containers/jdk-http/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jdkhttp/JdkHttpHandlerContainer.java#L152), you will see the `ContainerRequest`. I would just do something like

```
final ContainerRequest requestContext = new ContainerRequest(baseUri, requestUri,
                exchange.getRequestMethod(), getSecurityContext(exchange.getPrincipal(), isSecure),
                new MapPropertiesDelegate());
requestContext.setProperty(JdkServerProperties.REMOTE_IP_ADDR, exchange.getRemoteAddr());
```

Then in your [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9336), you can just do

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    // ContainerRequest implements ContainerRequestContext
    InetSockAddress remoteAddr = (InetSocketAddress) requestContext.getProperty(JdkServerProperties.REMOTE_IP_ADDR);
}
```

Yeah, so if I were to make a feature/pull request or just build my own artifact, this is probably the change I would make. Or if you don't want to expose the `InetSocketAddress`, you can just build the IP string and add that as the property value.